# How does blockchain and decentralization work?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, nodes, bitcoin, decentralization

Does every node or computer keep track of all of every user's transactions every single dollar as a separate unit or do they group together units in transactions? (eg. transfer of 5 dollars would be looked as one transaction or 5 different ones) Additionally, if every server records all user transactions ever, isn't there a space limit?

Answer (score 1):

These are broad questions. Let me try and answer as simple as possible.

First of all, bitcoin's an ethereum's accounting models are different:

- BTC uses an UTXO based accounting. The user spends what's called an **unspent transaction output** (UTXO). The balance for an account is the sum of all the UTXOs that account can spend.
- ETH uses an account based account system. The user spends from the balance they have available in an account.

You can read here about the differences and pros/cons of these accounting models.

The minimum accounting units (the *cents* equivalent in USD) are:

- Satoshis for bitcoin, where a satoshi represents 1 * 10 ^ -8 BTC
- Wei for ethereum, where 1 wei represents 1 * 10 ^ -18 ETH.

You can't transfer less than that minimum unit.

Regarding space, yes, there are theoretical limits, and that's why there are transaction fees - to put a cost on the space and computation costs required to secure the network.

Comment: It looks like you intended to include a link to the pros/cons of the two methods. Also, you can transfer 0 ether, which is less than one wei. This often happens when you're dealing with contracts such as ERC-20 tokens. (and you can even technically have a 0-cost transaction that transfers 0 tokens/ether if a miner requires no fees or you mine it yourself).